# How many people can go to your wedding?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

In Elder Scrolls Skyrim I decided to marry Lydia and some people assisted to our wedding: my Housecarls from Falkreath and Markarth, and the Jarl from Morthal. As you can imagine I was Thane of those regions and also I had helped the Jarl.

I'd like to know how many people can go to the wedding.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, the number of people that will attend your wedding is very limited, considering all of the people you encounter across Skyrim. It seems that you can have up to 7 guests (rare, from what I've seen), but 5-6 is a pretty good number. If what others have said is true, you can have 0 guests.

Users in [this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/skyrim/comments/5jz811/most_wedding_guests/) reported between 3 and 5 guests.

Users in [this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/skyrim/comments/3tca75/who_came_to_your_pitiful_wedding/) reported up to 6 guests.

Users in [this thread](http://skyrimforums.org/sf/threads/who-attended-your-wedding-in-riften.9837/) reported up to 6, but as low as 0 guests (not counting the priests that live there).

A user in [this thread](http://skyrimforums.org/sf/threads/who-attended-your-wedding.21255/) reported 7 attendees, but everyone else reported less.

From personal experience across a handful of save files, I've only ever seen 4-6 guests, picked seemingly randomly (Ysolda came to my wedding with Sylgja, for example).

Comment: Guests are determined by the friend status of the NPC. The more NPC you help and create friendship with and the more guests. Thus, marrying late could raise the number of guests.

Comment: I had 8 guests at my most recent characters wedding. Four from each side. I had married Vilkas.

Answer (score 0):

All I know is that if you have done the Companions Quest, some of the members will go to your wedding.